# Needed permissions to read msDS-ReplLinkFailures attribute

Tags: active-directory, powershell, ldap, attributes

I'm using powershell to get the value of msDS-ReplLinkFailures attribute like this:

```
Get-ADRootDSE -Properties msDS-ReplLinkFailures
```

This works ok if the current user is member of domain's Administrators group. When I run the above example using non admin user I don't get any results for msDS-ReplLinkFailures.

Is it possible to give a user/group rights to read msDS-ReplLinkFailures [since this attribute belongs to RootDSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223254.aspx)?

Comment: is there an error occuring? if so, please post it here. Does the same happen wenn you run this script with administrator privileges as a user?

Comment: @SimonS No, there's no error. The default attributes of RootDSE are shown but msDS-ReplLinkFailures just doesn't show up.

Comment: @SimonS In addition if I specify -Credential and enter user/pass for user that is member of Administrators - it works. So it's about permissions somewhere...

Comment: @SimonS interestingly the attribute "msDS-ReplLinkFailures" does not exist in AD Schema so its like a synthetic sugar. But I think the information is stored in some attribute in AD?